# How to Display Widget onPressed button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, widget

My goal is to display certain widgets based on clicks in a menu.
What I need when I click a title, is to show a certain widget.

Here is the full code:

```
    class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
      const SideMenu({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Drawer(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            // it enables scrolling
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DrawerHeader(
                    child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: defaultPadding * 3,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/logo/logo_icon.png",
                      scale: 5,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: defaultPadding,
                      
                    ),
                    Text("Récolt"),
                  ],
                )),
                DrawerListTile(
                  title: "Tableau de bord",
                  svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_dashbord.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                DrawerListTile(
                  title: "Utilisateurs",
                  svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_profile.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                DrawerListTile(
                  title: "Collaborateurs",
                  svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_doc.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                DrawerListTile(
                  title: "Producteurs",
                   svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_store.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                
                DrawerListTile(
                  title: "Paramètres",
                  svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_setting.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I've got a extern page to display my widget like this :

```
                            SizedBox(height: defaultPadding), 
                            ListUserEntreprise(),
                            SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
                            ListUserCollab(),
```

I don't know how to do it, I tried with using a boolean in `onPressed` but it didn't work, I don't know really how to declare it and use it with an external page. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

use StatefulWidget and try with a boolean with the onPressed, `setState()` to update UI

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SideMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideMenu({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SideMenu> createState() => _SideMenuState();
}

class _SideMenuState extends State<SideMenu> {
  bool _isShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        // it enables scrolling
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DrawerListTile(
              title: "Tableau de bord",
              svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_dashbord.svg",
              press: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isShow = !_isShow;
                });
              },
            ),
            Visibility(
                visible: _isShow,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('Tableau de bord'),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly.

I want when I click on a part of the menu, it shows a particular widget, which I call on a different page. Your code is displaying a text, which is a child of the widget. In my case, i need to have a boolean to display certain widget.How to link certain widget to a button, sorry if I express myself badly.